# Interview Question: If the newly added interval will overlap with K intervals in the interval list

Tags: algorithm, intervals

The problem statement is as follows:

> You are given a K core system, where at most K programs can run concurrently, and a list of programs L, where each program = [start, end], sorted in ascending order by start. Currently the all the programs can run without conflicts, meaning at any given time point, there are at most K concurrent programs running. Now we have a new program = [s0, e0], you need to determine if this program can be run on the system without conflicts.

I'm wondering if there is an O(n) (or faster) way to answer this.

I think this problem is asking

> After adding a new interval to the list, if it still has at most K overlapping intervals.

My idea is to build a `TreeMap`, whose keys are the all the endpoints(starts and ends) and values are the deltas on the number of intervals. For example, if we know an interval [a, b], then we update `treemap[a] += 1`, and `treemap[b] -= 1`. After all the intervals have been traversed, we scan the `TreeMap` again, calculate the sum of deltas, and record the maximum sum. And we just need to return `maxsum <= k`.

The problem with the approach is that it runs in O(nlogn) time because inserting into `TreeMap` takes O(logn) time. I saw some people claiming by doing binary search we can achieve O(n) time complexity, but I wasn't able to figure it out. I understand the problem with my previous approach is that I did not take advantage of the fact that the list is sorted based on start, but I still can't get how to do binary search on those intervals. Can anyone give a hint?

Comment: Unordered maps/dictionaries have O(1) time complexity generally

Comment: *"I saw some people claiming by doing binary search we can achieve O(n) time"* Doing a binary search on what?

Comment: @user3386109 Sorry for the confusion. Doing a binary search on the input list of intervals, which is sorted by start in ascending order.

Comment: Your approach is fine. Why not use a HashMap instead of TreeMap? That should give you O(n) solution.

Comment: @ShashankV You cannot use a hash map becuase you later need to iterate it in order. The whole idea of this approach is to have the data sorted, so you can later iterate it and see if the new interval can fit in.

Comment: It would be possible to get O(nlogk) instead of O(nlogn).

Comment: @maraca Thanks! That's also fine. Can you give a hint on how to do that?

Comment: @Patrick As you iterate through the list, place the `end` times into a priority queue (e.g. a min heap). For each interval, remove the `end` times that have expired, and then add the new `end` time to the queue. Since the problem statement guarantees at most K processes will be running at any point in time, the number of entries in the queue will be at most K.

Comment: @Patrick user3386109 is right, that's what I had in mind.